# 400-unknown or invalid client_id for forge-bim360-data.connector.dashboard

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I have tried to implement - https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-data.connector.dashboard
I have updated this part - `npm install set FORGE_CLIENT_ID=<<YOUR CLIENT ID FROM DEVELOPER PORTAL>> set FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET=<<YOUR CLIENT SECRET>> set FORGE_CALLBACK_URL=<<your callback url of Forge e.g. http://localhost:3000/oauth/callback>> set DC_CALLBACK_URL=<<"your ngrok address here: e.g. http://abcd1234.ngrok.io/job/callback">>`

I am getting the error that `400-Unknown or invalid client_id`

Comment: I guess you also put brackets (<<>>) with the id and secret. Could you share a screenshot how you run those scripts? put a shadow to hide the client id and secret . Like I did in this screenshot: https://ibb.co/BVcwgN2

Comment: @XiaodongLiang thank you for the response! Yes, Please find the screenshot here -https://ibb.co/7kSBHYj . I got this error when clicking on SIGN-IN tap on the right corner tap-- https://ibb.co/ySysZMg . and result url - https://auth.autodesk.com/as/authorization.oauth2?client_id=undefined&redirect_uri=undefined&response_type=code&pfidpadapterid=Oauth2OpenTokenIDPAdapter&scope=data:read%20data:write%20data:create&aud=https%3A%2F%2Fautodesk.com%2Faud%2Fajwtexp60

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake with the usage of Windows environment. Please check my answer in the formal reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I rarely used Windows OS now. I simply copied the guideline of setting environment variables from other samples, while most time, I tried with debug mode (setting environment variables in launch.json) .

checking the Readme again, I found the wording is:

```
   Windows (use Node.js command line from Start menu)
```

i.e. it asks to input those commands to command line of Node.js, instead of terminal of VSCode! That is why it always reports the error of client id is not defined because the variables are not set to environment  at all.

The correct way is to open the command line of Node.js, and run the commands. This is a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the updates. Now It has worked for me. I would just like to know one thing ie I am only able to see the dashboard of issues_issues.csv Please find the screenshot for the same- https://ibb.co/JqvmrqZ

Comment: I want to focus particularly on admin data as a priority. Could you please tell me how can implement a dashboard for the admin data for this one- https://ibb.co/qdCjjFV

Comment: firstly, I'd suggest you get familiar with  Chart.js:  https://www.chartjs.org/ to understand its logic of data, config and render in the dashboard. Next check how I implemented with Issue data https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-data.connector.dashboard/blob/main/www/js/dashboard.js ,  make a copy while design the dashboard with your own.